# FocusRequester not initialized when using if statement to conditionally show TextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, focus, composition

I'm creating a title bar that contains some text. The text cannot be edited by default and becomes editable when the `edit button` is clicked

```
var value by remember { mutableStateOf("jordan") }
val onValueChange: (String) -> Unit = {
    value = it
}
val focusRequester = remember{ FocusRequester() }
var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
        .fillMaxSize(),
) {
    Text(
        text = "isFocused: $isFocused",
        style = ts400,
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black)
    )

    if(isFocused) {
        TextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    isFocused = it.isFocused
                }
        )
    } else {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = value,
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            )
            IconButton(onClick = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Edit,
                    tint = Color.White,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

However, when i click the `edit button`. The app crashes and the following `error` is logged `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FocusRequester is not initialized`

I played around with the code and realized the `edit button` works as it should without the `if` statement but taking out the `if` defeats the purpose of the title bar

Comment: When the if condition is false, you are showing the edit button which has an onClick action to focus the `TextField`. But the `TextField` is not in the Compose tree at this point as the `if` condition is `false`. You are trying to focus an element that does not exist on the screen.

Comment: @Abhimanyu what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are requesting focus while composing which is causing the Error. You must call using `SideEffects`.

Because `Jetpack Compose` don't know how much time it would take to focus. you must run this login inside the `LaunchedEffect` block so it will run independently.

Here some changes your can made to your code is take one variable which will oversee visibility of the `TextField`.

and then rather than checking for focus check whether your `TextField` should be displayed or not.

And Then if TextField SHould be visible then you can request focust using `LaunchedEffect`.

Here is your modified code. You can follow

```
@Composable
fun ActionBarEdit() {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf("jordan") }
    val onValueChange: (String) -> Unit = {
        value = it
    }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "isFocused: $isFocused",
            modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black)
        )

        if (isVisible) {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
            TextField(
                value = value,
                onValueChange = onValueChange,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        isFocused = it.isFocused
                    }
            )
        } else {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = value,
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                )
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    isVisible = true
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Edit,
                        tint = Color.White,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: preview]